# css and other static files not working in django

Tags: python, django

The current project I've started working on, uses django 2.2 and most of the links are hardcoded.

All static content is in folder named **media** and used in base.html as follows

**in base.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %} ---- using this as first line of base.html
.......
.......
<head>
<link href="/media/css/backoffice/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```

**in settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```

I've also added following to the main urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Yet I'm not able to render the static file listed in the head section of base.html

I've also experimented with commenting out static root and staticfiles_dir but it does not work

Comment: from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/) you can just `{% load static %}` at the start of the template and use `href ="{% static "css/backoffice/font-awesome.min.css" %}"` to load the static files

Comment: @LinhNguyen : what you are suggesting is the best practice as per the Django documentation. I have authority to make changes to settings file and make it run. any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: i'm not quite clear what you mean from `I have authority to make changes to settings file and make it run`, so what stopping you?

Comment: i cannot make changes to the base.html file .. so css links in head cannot be changed. I can only change the STATIC_URL, STATIC_ROOT or STATICFILES_DIRS

Comment: then there not much or any options as django template render base on the template tag itself to do file import

Answer (score 0):

You need to put all files in project root's static folder and run this command:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

For loading static files in the template you need to write this:

```
{% load static %}
```

And in all the static files like `css`, `js` and `images` you can do like this:

```
{% static "<absolute path of file>" %}
```

And you can refer from [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/).

I hope this will help you!

Comment: i don't the authority to change static file's location and what you are suggesting is the best practice. Files need to be in media folder. I'm assuming there should be an option to make changes to STATIC_URL ,  STATICFILES_DIRS or STATIC_ROOT to make it work